# MSAL not redirecting to Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

I'm playing around with MSAL (Microsoft Identity Client) preview 1.1.2, and am stuck during the sign in process, where it does not redirect my application back to the Android application.

My Xamarin application is a Prism-generated Android application, and I believe I have everything sorted.

In the `App.xaml.cs` file, have:

```
public static UIParent UiParent { get; set; }

public static PublicClientApplication ClientApplication { get; set; }

public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };
```

Then, in the App constructor, I have:

```
public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer)
{
    ClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication("my-app-id");
}
```

Please take into account, this is a Prism-generated application.

Then, in my `MainPageViewModel.cs` file, I have a command trigger the button click, with the following code:

```
private async void OnAuthenticate()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await App.ClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, App.UiParent);
        Message = $"Welcome {result.User.Name}";
    }
    catch (MsalException ex)
    {
        Message = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

To correctly parse the UIParent, I updated the MainActivity.cs file in the Droid project, to:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    // omitted...
    LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    App.UiParent = new UIParent(this);
}
```

and:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

If I cancel the sign-in process, I get a message back saying "User cancelled authentication", which is correct, but the sign-in process just never redirects me back to the Android application.

The Redirect URI in my application is this:

```
msal{my-app-id}://auth
```

which, according to most of the blogs I read on MSAL and Xamarin, is what it should be.

Don't know why it's not working for me?

Comment: Good question, im also trying to find an answer to this... If i find anything ill let you know

Comment: You have to update the Android Manifest to 'retrieve' the callback to your specified redirect uri. I only got MSAL working for standard Windows account, I could not get it to work with VSTS, because VSTS apps require a physical uri, and it does not seem MSAL can handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem recently with the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/1-Basic) solution provided on github.

The initial answer above is one option, but this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations#update-the-android-manifest) from Microsoft explains it better with example code. You can update the android manifest:

```
<activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="msal{client_id}" android:host="auth" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

or create the activity in code:

```
  [Activity]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
        DataHost = "auth",
        DataScheme = "msal{client_id}")]
  public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
  {
  }
```

Either way, once the client ID is set correctly it should redirect back to your app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like JadedEric mentioned is a matter of updating your **AndroidManifest.xml** file for android and for IOS updating your **info.plist** file. please look at the following post as they explain exactly what to place in those files: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2

Also another important thing here is that you have to make sure that your app registered in azure has the same RedirectURI as the one placed in the manfiest.xml and the info.plist. this is key to get that redirect working (thats the `msal{my-app-id}://auth` you mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you haven't updated your *AndroidManifest.xml* file with the return auth url "*msal{clientID}*".

e.g.:

```
&lt;data android:scheme="msalxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" android:host="auth" /&gt;
```